# Retopoflow 3: symetry issue

Tags: retopology

I am sculpting my first Character and i have to do Retopology since I reached + 3M Polycount.
The character is mosty symetric containing some asymetric parts. My Idea was to do the retopo on a symetric version (Generated with Automirror). And manually adjust the asymetric parts later on.

I am using Blender 2.91 and Retopoflow 3.00.2.

Here is where I got stuck:

If i start Retopoflow and turn symetry on i cant see a symetry line. The Whole Object turns red instead and none of the tools works.

[image]

If I switch symetry of everything  works as expected. Also, symetry works fine with the monkey face. It seems something is wrong with my Object, but I cant figure out what it is. I tried lowering Polycount (350k) which did not fix the issue. I really would like to use Retopoflow and I dont know how to move on. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on edge selection mode at the top left of the 3D viewport window. You have it on face select mode currently.